# Efficient way to copy or merge two ArrayList containing same objects

Tags: java, android, collections

I have an Object like below

```
Product {

String name;

boolean isFiltered;

}
```

We have two lists - masterProductList and filteredProductList containing product.

We have to copy values of filteredProductList(this list has property isFiltered set) to masterProductList.

I can do it with following approches -

Approach 1

```
for (Product filterProduct: filteredPL) {
    for (Product masterProduct: masterPL) {
        if (filterProduct.equals(masterProduct)) {
            // Copy Values
            masterProduct.setIsFiltered(filterProduct.getIsFiltered());
        }
    }
}
```

Approach 2

```
for (Product filterProduct: filteredPL) {
    for (Product masterProduct: masterPL) {
        //Delete the old product having old values
        masterProduct.remove(filterProduct);
        //Add product with new values
        masterProduct.add(filterProduct);
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches have **n square** complexity.

Is there any other better way to do this so that we can reduce the complexity?

Comment: if you want to remove duplicates add both to a hashset.

Comment: See my answer. With better complexity

Comment: approach 2 has n^3 complexity.

Comment: This statement appears to do nothing: `masterProduct.setIsFiltered(masterProduct.getIsFiltered());`
was it supposed to be: `masterProduct.setIsFiltered(filterProduct.getIsFiltered());` ?

Comment: Is this by any chance for a RecyclerView?

Comment: @elmorabea, yes its for RecyclerView. I need to reflect filtered list to master list.

Comment: @ankitpatidar, yes it is better than those approaches. Thank you.

Comment: @rguessford, I edited the post. Thanks for noticing that. There are two for loops, how complexity is n^3. Can please elaborate it?

Comment: Nagesh please accept it

Comment: @tiborK, I am not trying to remove duplicates.

Comment: @NageshJatagond Maybe consider using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

Comment: @NageshJatagond `masterProduct.remove(filterProduct);` is an O(n) operation. For proof, [check out the implementation.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thank you @rguessford. Internally its running for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create code as:

```
 Hashmap<String, Boolean> merged =new Hashmap<>();

 for(Product product : masterList)
       Merged.put(product.getName(), product.isfiltered());

 for(Product product : filteredList)
       Merged.put(product.getName(), product.isfiltered());
```

Here is solution for combining for list. Here if name is in both array list so that it can be unique in hashmap with a value of `filteredlist` as per your requirement.

And one major thing here complexity is very less

O(n + n) = O(2n) = `O(n)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could convert your main product list to a hashset which has constant time access methods.

```
Set<Product> masterPLHS = new HashSet<Product>(masterPL); // O(n)

for (Product filterProduct: filteredPL) { //O(n)
        if (masterPLHS.contains(filterProduct)) {  //O(1)
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except `contains` is O(n). (see my answer below)

Comment: Set.contains() is O(1). ArrayList.contains() is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

What about using a third list. Using a third list prevent `contains` to include the added elements in the search.

```
List<Object> listA;
List<Object> listB;

List<Object> listMerged = new List<>(); // init listMerged
listMerged.addAll(listA);
for(Object elt: listB){
    if (!listA.contains(elt))
        listMerged.add(elt);
}
```

Comment: what do you think what is the time complexity of contains?

Comment: so the final time complexity is n^2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Set<Product> masterPLHS = new HashSet<Product>(masterPL);

for (Product filterProduct: filteredPL) { 
      masterPLHS.add(filterProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also should work:

```
List<Product> merged = filteredProductList.stream().filter(masterProductList::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: but I suppose it is n^2 because of `contains` method